# How to run ASP.NET web api from github

Tags: c#, asp.net, angular, git, github

I am new in asp.net  and angular development.I dont know how to run asp.net web api from github. As we run angular code by using "ng build --prod --base-href https://ownername.github.io/repositoryname/ so i want to know could we run asp.net web api by using such kind of any command or something other which is used for this.
Basically i want to run my project on  network i tried by IIS server but no result is showing so now i want to try github process
Help would be appricated

Comment: I believe github.io simply serves static files.  An asp.net web api is something you would run on a server, such as behind IIS or with `dotnet run` locally if using dotnet core.  The easiest way to get it running for dev would be to use Visual Studio or VS Code.  Have you had a look at the [ASP.NET Getting Started](https://www.asp.net/get-started)?

Comment: Sir i run the code on localhost  its working fine but the issue is with on network. I want to use my site on network if you can provide nay refrence or help than i would be really thankful to you

Comment: what's your build environment for the web api?  Are you using dotnet core cli, vs code or visual studio?

Answer (score 5):

asp.net core apps have to run in a .net core process on a server so the hosting environment needs to specifically support this.  a variety of web servers can be configured to proxy the requests. Unfortunately, I don't think GitHub allows running app processes for asp.net core.

However you ca easily deploy to azure with even a free account
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/publish-to-azure-webapp-using-vs?view=aspnetcore-2.2